# Cannot define inter dependent relationships among models using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In following code examples `ChatMessage` model has required field `converstaion_id` which defines the relationship with `ChatConversation` of that model. `ChatConverstation` model has a field `last_message_id` which is the reference to the last `ChatMessage`.

I am getting following error message from `sqlalchemy` and do not know how to resolve this issue. Please help.

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class ChatConversation->chat_conversation, expression 'ChatMessage' failed to locate a name ('ChatMessage'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'chat.models.conversation.ChatConversation'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.

How should I define schema for these models so that I can set both relationships (ie. `conversation` relationship in `ChatMessage` model and `last_message` relationship in `ChatConversation` model) ?

```py
class ChatConversation(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'chat_conversation'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  last_message_id = db.Column(
      db.Integer,
      db.ForeignKey("chat_message.id", ondelete='SET NULL'),
      nullable = True
  )
  last_message = db.relationship('ChatMessage')
```

```py
class ChatMessage(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'chat_message'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  conversation_id = db.Column(
      db.Integer,
      db.ForeignKey("chat_conversation.id", ondelete='CASCADE'),
      nullable=False
  )
  conversation = db.relationship('ChatConversation')
```

Comment: You can't have circular foreign key references.  Not allowed.  In part, that would make it impossible to delete some records safely.  You can make it an integer.

Comment: If I removed the foreign key constraint from `last_message_id` would I be able to populate data in `last_message` relationship without any issues?

Comment: I believe so, but you'll have to do it as an integer, not as a `ChatMessage` instance.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I defined the relationship using `hybrid_propery`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `hybrid_property` method decorator from `sqlalchemy` and define `foreign_keys` explicitly to resolve the ambiguity of `ForeignKey`.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class ChatConversation(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'chat_conversation'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  last_message_id = db.Column(
      db.Integer,
      db.ForeignKey("chat_message.id", ondelete='SET NULL'),
      nullable = True
  )
  
  @hybrid_property
  def last_message(self):
    return False if not self.last_message_id else ChatMessage.query.get(self.last_message_id)
```

```py
class ChatMessage(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'chat_message'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  conversation_id = db.Column(
      db.Integer,
      db.ForeignKey("chat_conversation.id", ondelete='CASCADE'),
      nullable=False
  )
  conversation = db.relationship('ChatConversation', foreign_keys = [conversation_id])
```